# TinyMCE code plugin Internet Explorer radio buttons checked attribute removed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cakephp, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a site in cakephp 1.3 with tinymce 4.1.7 and I am saving html content in the tiny mce window.

I insert the following markup into the tiny mce textarea

```
<div>
     <input id="Form1" name="data[Form][1]" type="radio" value="form1" />
     <label for="Form1">Form 1 </label>

     <input id="Form2" checked="checked" name="data[Form][2]" type="radio" value="Form 2" /> 
     <label for="Form2">Form 2 </label>
</div>
```

In Chrome and Firefox I can save my html and it will get properly stored in the mysql database. when i load the page again to edit the html everything looks fine.

In IE11 I load the page after the html was stored and the page loads with the "checked" attribute missing. Tiny mce displays the radio button as checked but in the source code window and upon inspecting the tinymce content the checked attribute is now longer present in IE.

When i removed the tinymce plugin and just echoed the content into a regular textarea the attribute was present and there were no issues. I don't understand how tinymce only has this problem when I use it in IE.

It only seems to be the checked attribute that is affected.

Comment: After some more testing i have found that the tinymce editor and the html content works properly when compatability mode is set to IE 8 or older. It seems as thought this issue happens in IE 9 thru IE 11 and Edge

Comment: Hi, have a look in your database at the actual record saved... I expect that it will look like class=" checked="checked ........ you will need to escape the markup before you store it in the db. it should look like.. class=\"\" checked=\"checked\" ..... I think the DOMParser.parseFromString() method will do it for you.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: serializeToString method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ok I looked at my database and i do not really understand where the need is for escaping characters. to make things simpler I changed the html I am embedding. Regardless of the db I have found that this stripping of the checked attribute only happens when the page is loaded in IE 9 thru IE11 and Edge. In Chrome and Firefox the checked attribute is present when the page loads.